# C ({ .. }) structure: parenthesis followed by curly brace

Tags: c

I wonder what kind of expression is ({ .. statements .. }) in C?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x = ({
            const int i = 10;
            i*2;
    });
    printf("Result: %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

The above code returns 20.
So it seems like the statements in ({ .. }) are executed and the result of the last statement returned?
What type of construction is it? Where do I read more about it?

Comment: I find it amazing that you still have to pay to get the C language standard documents.

Comment: @jarmod -- there is a hyperlinked copy of the [C11 Draft Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html) available online. There is also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents) with several sources for pdfs. But the Standard does not provide answers to questions about compiler-specific features such as this.

Comment: @exnihilo thanks, that's helpful, particularly that this is not standard C, but a gcc extension.